# Can MySQL database name be numeric?

Tags: mysql, database, naming-conventions, fully-qualified-naming

MySQL wont let me create a database name that only has numbers. It only works when I add letters.

How do I create a database name in MySQL that only uses numbers?

`CREATE DATABASE 2752054;`

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/identifiers.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It should be possible, if quoted. See [9.2 Schema Object Names](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html) - there is no relevant special clause added to identifiers used for database (as opposed to table) names for this case.

> Identifiers may begin with a digit *but unless quoted may not consist solely of digits*.

```
CREATE DATABASE `2752054`;
```

However, I'd encourage use of at least a meaningful prefix..